# PHP odd parse errors

Tags: php, php-7.1

So I'm pulling my hair out at this point :/

I've got an IIS webserver set up with PHP 7.1.11 on Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter Edition , when I load up a page it throws a parse error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in functions.php on line 138
```

Now the actual piece of code where this goes wrong is the following

```
$hash = password_hash($nieuwWachtwoord,PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ["cost" => 13]);
```

And when I changed it to

```
$hash = password_hash($nieuwWachtwoord,PASSWORD_DEFAULT,array("cost" => 13));
```

It executes the code without any problem.

But then when I called another function running the following code

```
 Database::fetch_assoc("SQL-STRING", array($id))[0]['cdate'];
```

It also throws a parse error. The frustrating thing is that this shouldn't happen since declaring an array like that on the go should be possible in php7.1 (and this same code on a Linux machine running ubuntu with apache2 works like it should)

Also the last case where I "assume" an array is returned should at most throw an undefined index error instead of a parse error.

Does anyone know what the cause may be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How certain are you that this is running PHP 7? You've confirmed this with `phpinfo()`? What's the parse error message for the `Database::fetch_assoc` code?

Comment: I have, it's running PHP 7.1.11 x64. That's also the first thing I checked since I thought that it was a php 5.3 thing. Parse error for the `Database::fetch_assoc` code is exactly the same.

Comment: I'm curious about *how* you checked, though. It's possible for there to be multiple versions of PHP on a server. If you replace the `password_hash()` line with `phpinfo()` the output shows PHP 7? What do the couple of lines before/after the problematic line say?

Comment: try it running on php 5.6

Comment: Well that being a good point. I checked it in the root of the website  (test.php) that shows up as 7.1.11. But when I try it in the script that actually loads the functions.php file. It happily tells me I'm running PHP 5.3 :/ . So much thanks for that suggestion. Now for the new odd thing, why does my PHP version switch to 5.3 when I go into deeper directories (test.php is in the root) functions.php is 1 folder deeper..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay thanks to ceejayoz I found out the problem.
When I put phpinfo() in a file called test.php it told me I was running PHP 7.1 .

Now the file actually calling the script that was throwing parse errors had a .html extension. And IIS had a different Handler mapping for html files pointing to the old 5.3 executable.

Now that I changed the handler for .html files it all works like a charm again!

Many thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. :-)